# Mount docker postgres volumn to ubuntu existing postgres data

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My ubuntu 18.04 has installed postgresql locally. I want to mount existing data to docker.

The below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /etc/postgresql/10/main:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I did not change default postgres 10 config in Ubuntu. As default, I think the config is located in `/etc/postgresql/10/main` and data is located in `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`.

If I set

```
volumes:
   - /var/lib/postgresql/10/main:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

It warns

```
db_1     | postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

If I change to

```
volumes:
      - /etc/postgresql/10/main:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

It warns

```
db_1     | initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
db_1     | If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
db_1     | the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
db_1     | with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

How to work it out without create a new local docker volumn by `docker volume create pgdata`

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to specify both into the same directory:

```
volumes:
    - "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    - "/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf"
```